# Download file in base64 efficiently

Tags: java, download, base64

I have to download an arbitrarily large file in base64 in a device with limited RAM memory in Java.

How do I download a file in base64 efficiently? Is it possible to get sequential chunks of base64 and write them to the output as binary data?

A code or pseudo-code example would be much appreciated.

**Note**: I can't use external frameworks, but I have base64 decode and encode functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a stream to decode the base64.

You can use the [common codec library](http://commons.apache.org/codec/), but if you don't want to use an external library, you could use [this code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/BASE64DecoderStream.htm) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Open two streams. One to remote file, another to a local file. Download remote file into a buffer and pass the buffer to other stream for writing to the local file.